# How can I build an immutable tree datastructure in Scala?

Tags: scala, tree, immutability, trie

I am attempting to construct an immutable Trie defined as such:

```
case class Trie(children: Map[Char, Trie] = Map.empty[Char, Trie], value: Option[String] = None)
```

With the following extension methods:

```
extension (t: Trie)
  def addAll(words: Seq[String]): Trie =
    words.foldLeft(new Trie())(_.insert(_))

  def insert(word: String): Trie =
    var cur = t
    word.foreach(c => {
      if !cur.children.contains(c) then
        cur = cur.copy(children = cur.children + (c -> new Trie()))
      end if
      cur = cur.children.get(c).get
    })
    cur.copy(value = Some(word))
```

My issue at present is with the `insert` method specifically: I've tried a number of different approaches, but all my attempts fail to return the root of the Trie, i.e. I am unable to insert new nodes in such a way that an entire branch from the root node to leaf is copied along with the newly inserted node.

To further illustrate, the following:

```
@main def hello: Unit =
  println(new Trie().insert("bot").insert("bat"))
```

Simply results in: `Trie(Map(),Some(bat))`

I am new to Scala and FP in general, so I am unsure of best approaches here.

Comment: You need to work with a Zipper: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure). There is a Scala 2 implementation here: https://github.com/stanch/zipper. Take a look to  see how it works.

Comment: What is the purpose/function of the `value` member? After `.insert("in").insert("it")` what should the root node (the `'i'` node) `value` be and why?

Comment: @jwvh `value` serves to indicate whether the current node is a terminal node, signifying that the path from the root to that node represent a full word in our trie. For example after a call to `.insert("in").insert("it")` we have something like  -> `Trie(Map(i -> Trie(Map(n -> Trie(Map(), Some(in)))), t -> Trie(Map(), Some(it)),  None)`

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez thanks for that tip! i've gone down a rabbit hole here, currently looking into possibly using monocle/lens to update the nodes as desired. will update my post If i am successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appears to get at what you're after.

```
case class Trie(children : Map[Char, Trie] = Map()
               ,value    : Option[String]  = None):
  def insert(word: String, index: Int = 0): Trie =
    word.lift(index).fold(copy(value=Some(word))){c =>
      copy(children + (c -> children.getOrElse(c,Trie()).insert(word, index+1)))
    }
```

testing:

```
Trie().insert("inn").insert("in")
//Trie(Map(i -> Trie(Map(n -> Trie(Map(n -> Trie(Map(),Some(inn))),Some(in))),None)),None)
```

Comment: ah, great stuff @jwvh. This seems to do accomplish exactly what I was after. A lot to unpack here, but I think I have the general gist of the approach, thanks!

Comment: This does not look tail recursive. Would it use up all the stack on longer inputs?